# Loop calling an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**Introduction to the problem**

I need to call an asynchronous function within a loop until a condition is satisfied. This particular function sends a POST request to a website *form.php* and performs some operations with the response, which is a JSON string representing an object with an *id* field. So, when that id is null, the outer loop must conclude. The function does something like the following:

```js
function asyncFunction(session) {
    (new Request({
        url: form.php,
        content: "sess=" + session,
        onComplete: function (response) {
            var response = response.json;
            if (response.id) {
                doStaff(response.msg);
            } else {
                // Break loop
            }
        }
    })).get();
}
```

**Note**: Although I've found the problem implementing an add-on for Firefox, I think that this is a general javascript question.

---

**Implementing the loop recursively**

I've tried implementing the loop by recursivity but it didn't work and I'm not sure that this is the right way.

```js
...
    if (response.id) {
        doStaff(response.msg);
        asyncFunction(session);
    } else {
        // Break loop
    }
...
```

**Using jsdeferred**

I also have tried with the jsdeferred library:

```js
 Deferred.define(this);
 //Instantiate a new deferred object
 var deferred = new Deferred(); 

 // Main loop: stops when we receive the exception
 Deferred.loop(1000, function() {
      asyncFunction(session, deferred);
      return deferred;
 }).
 error(function() {
     console.log("Loop finished!");
 });
```

And then calling:

```js
...
    if (response.id) {
        doStaff(response.msg);
        d.call();
    } else {
        d.fail();
    }
...
```

And I achieve serialization but it started repeating previous calls for every iteration. For example, if it was the third time that it called the asyncFunction, it would call the same function with the corresponding parameters in the iterations 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not exactly clear, but the basic architecture must be that the completion event handlers for the asynchronous operation must decide whether to try again or to simply return.  If the results of the operation warrant another attempt, then the handler should call the parent function.  If not, then by simply exiting the cycle will come to an end.

You can't code something like this in JavaScript with anything that looks like a simple "loop" structure, for the very reason that the operations are **asynchronous**.  The results of the operation don't happen in such a way as to allow the looping mechanism to perform a test on the results; the loop may run thousands of iterations before the result is available. To put it another way, you don't "wait" for an asynchronous operation with code. You wait by doing nothing, and allowing the registered event handler to take over when the results are ready.

Comment: I see what you mean but, then, what other strategy can I use? There must be some pattern to perform something like what I'm trying to do, right?

Comment: I just described the strategy. There are some different forms the code can take, but basically you have no choice. @Kayo gives an example with actual code, but you'll see that within the "done" function (which will be triggered by the completion of the async procedure), the "newAsyncRequest" function is called.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for your help. This is what I ended doing:

```js
var sess = ...;
Deferred.define(this);      
function asyncFunction (session) {
    Deferred.next(function() {
        var d = new Deferred();
        (new Request({
              url: form.php,
              content: "sess=" + session,
              onComplete: function (response) {
                  d.call(response.json);
              }
        })).get();
        return d;
    }).next(function(resp) {
        if (resp.id) {
            asyncFunction(session);
            console.log(resp.msg);              
        }           
    });
}

asyncFunction(sess);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just use a setInterval loop? In the case of an SDK-based extension, this would look like:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1065247/latest/

The big benefit of promises-like patterns over using timers is that you can do things in parallel, and use much more complicated dependencies for various tasks. A simple loop like this is done just as easily / neatly using setInterval.

Comment: +1 I like it, but imagine that the request takes longer than 150ms. Then, some iterations of the loop will overlap asynchronously, right? I don't want overlapings... I want it serialized.

Comment: Btw, I found this useful tutorial [API-promises](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.7/packages/api-utils/promise.html). But I can't import the promise library into my add-on..

Comment: For the SDK's own promise library, you import it like this: const { reject } = require('api-utils/promise'); Does that not work?

Comment: No, it gives me an error:

`error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://ares-at-iiia-dot-csic/api-utils/lib/promise.js", line 16, in 
    }.call(this, function(require, exports) {
  ...
  File "((function (require, exports) {"use strict"", line NaN, in 
  File "resource://ares-at-iiia-dot-csic/api-utils/lib/globals!.js", line 75, in getter
    value: define.bind(this)
TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property 'define'`
(I just wrote the begining and the end, it doesn't fit in a comment)

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you want to do, **Deferred** is a good approach. Here's an example using **jQuery** which has Deferred functionality built in (`jQuery.Deferred`)

A timeout is used to simulate an http request.  When each timeout is complete (or http request is complete) a random number is returned which is equivalent to the result of your http request.

Based on the result of the request you can decide if you need another http request or want to stop.

Try out the below snippet. Include the jQuery file and then the snippet.  It keeps printing values in the console and stops after a zero is reached.

This could take while to understand but useful.

```
$(function() {

    var MAXNUM = 9;

    function newAsyncRequest() {
        var def = $.Deferred(function(defObject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                defObject.resolve(Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAXNUM+1)));
            }, 1000);
        });

        def.done(function(val) {
            if (val !== 0)
                newAsyncRequest();
            console.log(val);
        });

    };

    newAsyncRequest();
});
```

Update after suggestion from @canuckistani

@canuckistani [is correct in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441818/1208799).  For this problem the solution is simpler. Without using Deferred the above code snippet becomes the following. Sorry I led you to a tougher solution.

```
$(function() {

    var MAXNUM = 9;

    function newAsyncRequest() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var val = Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAXNUM+1));
            if (val !== 0)
                newAsyncRequest();
            console.log(val);
        }, 1000);
    }

    newAsyncRequest();

});
```

Comment: +1 Yes, that is what I want. I'll try to understand it and implement it in my add-on. When I finish I'll post the final answer. Thank you!

Comment: I think that the resolve-done pattern could be implemented with the call function of jsdeferred: [jsdeferredAPI](http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/doc/Deferred.html#Deferred#call)

Comment: @Kits89 I took a look at **jsdeferredAPI**. `call` in jsdeferred seems the equivalent of `resolve` in jQuery.Deferred. Likewise, `next` *seems* to be the equivalent of `done` in jQuery.Deferred, although not so certain.  It might be a good idea to first verify if the above snippet works after adapting it to use [jsdeferredAPI](http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/doc/Deferred.html#Deferred#call) instead of [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: yes, you're right: call is the equivalent to resolve and next to done. 

Yes, the snipped works I've already checked that in a javascript console. But I can't execute jquery in a library file of a jetpack add-on. That's why I need to make that conversion. But I finally did it, check my answer.