# Chaining multiple asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, promise

**Introduction**

I have a question coming from this one:

[Loop calling an asynchronous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434320/loop-calling-an-asynchronous-function)

Once I got a loop that calls an asynchronous function using a promises-like pattern (jsdeferred library in an add-on developed with SDK).

```js
var sess = ...;
Deferred.define(this);      
function asyncFunction (session) {
    Deferred.next(function() {
        var d = new Deferred();
        (new Request({
              url: form.php,
              content: "sess=" + session,
              onComplete: function (response) {
                  d.call(response.json);
              }
        })).get();
        return d;
    }).next(function(resp) {
        if (resp.id) {
            asyncFunction(session);
            console.log(resp.msg);              
        }           
    });
}

asyncFunction(sess);
```

I want to chain a new asynchrnous function into this request, for example, opening a browser's tab: I don't want to continue the execution until is ready.

**Problem**

So I get to this:

```js
var sess = ...;
Deferred.define(this);      
function asyncFunction (session) {
    Deferred.next(function() {
        var d = new Deferred();
        (new Request({
              url: form.php,
              content: "sess=" + session,
              onComplete: function (response) {
                  d.call(response.json);
              }
        })).get();
        return d;
    })
    .next(function(resp) {
        var d = new Deferred();
        // Load tab
        tabs.activeTab.url = 'http://foo.com';
        tabs.activeTab.on('ready', function() {
            console.log(resp.id);
            d.call(resp.id); 
        });
        return d;
    })
    .next(function(resp) {
        if (resp.id) {
            asyncFunction(session);
            console.log(resp.msg);              
        }           
    });
}

asyncFunction(sess);
```

And the result that I get is that, for each iteration of the loop, it runs all the previous requests again! So I got the following log in my console:

```
id1
msg1
id1
msg1
id2
msg2
id1
msg1
id2
msg2
id3
msg3
...
```

Obviously what I expected was:

```
id1
msg1
id2
msg2
id3
msg3
```

**Question**

It's crystal clear that I don't understand the promises pattern. I've read a lot in two APIs:

- [jsdeferred](http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/#behavior)
- [FF add-on sdk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/packages/api-utils/promise.html)

The first is the one I've been using until now. The second one gives an error when I try to require the library:

```js
const { defer } = require('api-utils/promise'); (+)
```

So, my question is if you know any good tutorial of promises or some good example about **chaining multiple asynchronous functions**. Or if you know how to do it, how would you do it.

Thank you

**EDIT: The error that gives the line (+)**

```
error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://ares-at-iiia-dot-csic/api-utils/lib/promise.js", line 16, in 
    }.call(this, function(require, exports) {
  File "resource://ares-at-iiia-dot-csic/api-utils/lib/promise.js", line 6, in return     function promised
    if (typeof(define) === 'function') { // RequireJS
  File "function promisedConcat(promises, unknown) {return promises.then(function         (values) {return resolve(unknown).then(function (valu
e) {return values.concat(value);});});", line NaN, in function promisedConcat
  File "function execute(args) {return call.apply(call, args);", line NaN, in function     execute
  File "exports.reject = reject;var promised = function () {var call =     Function.call;var concat = Array.prototype.concat", line NaN, in
 exports.reject = reject;var promised = function 
  File "function reject(reason, prototype) {var deferred =         defer(prototype);deferred.reject(reason);return deferred.promise;", line NaN
, in function reject
  File "exports.resolve = resolve", line NaN, in exports.resolve = resolve
  File "function resolve(value, prototype) {var deferred =     defer(prototype);deferred.resolve(value);return deferred.promise;", line NaN
, in function resolve
  File "exports.defer = defer", line NaN, in exports.defer = defer
  File "if (pending) {pending.push([resolved, rejected]);} else {result.then(resolved,     rejected);}return deferred.promise;}}});var defe
rred = {promise: promise, resolve: function resolve(value) {if (pending) {result =     isPromise(value) ? value : resolution(value);while (
pending.length) {result.then.apply(result, pending.shift());}pending = null;}},     reject", line NaN, in if 
  File "function rejected(reason) {deferred.resolve(reject(reason));", line NaN, in     function rejected
  File "function resolved(value) {deferred.resolve(resolve(value));", line NaN, in     function resolved
  File "function defer(prototype) {var pending = [], result;prototype = prototype ||     prototype === null ? prototype : Object.prototype;
var promise = Object.create(prototype, {then: {value: function then(resolve, reject)     {var deferred = defer(prototype);resolve = resolve
 ? attempt(resolve) : resolution;reject = reject ? attempt(reject) ", line NaN, in     function defer
  File "function isPromise(value) {return value && typeof value.then === "function";",     line NaN, in function isPromise
  File "function attempt(f) {return function effort(options) {try {return f(options);}     catch (error) {return rejection(error);}};", lin
e NaN, in function attempt
  File "function rejection(reason) {return {then", line NaN, in function rejection
  File "function resolution(value) {return {then", line NaN, in function resolution
  File "((function (require, exports) {"use strict"", line NaN, in 
  File "resource://ares-at-iiia-dot-csic/api-utils/lib/globals!.js", line 75, in getter
    value: define.bind(this)
TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property 'define'
```

Comment: Is your Add-on SDK version current? The `promise` module was added in Add-on SDK 1.7.

Comment: Yes, I have the version 1.8. And I've found the library in the api-utils folder. I'll edit in order to post the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, looks a bit like a scoping issue. In your last function, there should be no variable `resp` available - I'm not sure what it really logs.

And yes, because you call `asyncFunction` once again in the end, as long as there is an id in the response, you might get an endless loop.

However, lets try to use the [add-on sdk's promises](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/packages/api-utils/promise.html) (and no, I've never used them before - but it says it was based on [CommonJS Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A)):

```
const { defer } = require('api-utils/promise');
// or whatever you need in your code to use them - I'm no addOn-developer

var sess = ...;
Deferred.define(this);      
function asyncFunction (session) {
/* returns a promise itself */

    var d = defer();
    (new Request({
        url: form.php,
        content: "sess=" + session,
        onComplete: function (response) {
            d.resolve(response.json);
        }
    })).get();
    return d.promise.then(function(resp) {
        var d = defer();
        // Load tab
        tabs.activeTab.url = 'http://foo.com';
        tabs.activeTab.on('ready', function() {
            d.resolve(resp);
        });
        return d.promise;
    }).then(function(resp) {
        console.log("request #"+resp.id+"sucessful: "+resp.msg);  
        if (resp.id) {
            asyncFunction(session); // call recursively
        }           
    });
}
asyncFunction(sess);
```

Comment: you're right, in fact this is how actually looks my code. `def` and `resp` were mistakes when I wrote the question, sorry. The code you wrote prints exaclty the same results, repeating the previous iterations. It seems to me that making the `tab.activeTab.url = 'http://foo.com'` triggers the handler of previous iterations. Is that possible?

Comment: Um, yes. Does the "ready" event fire more than once? It looks like this promise library does allow multiple invocation of a "Deferred" - usually deferreds can only once fullfil or fail.

Comment: yes, it's fired every time that `tabs.activeTab.url = 'http://foo.com';` is executed. @Bergi: do you know how to use the promise library of the add-on SDK that I posted in this question?

Comment: but, anyway, the onComplete event is also fired every iteration and it doesn't give any error.

Comment: No, that line is executed only once for every Deferred `d`, isn't it?. I should have asked whether `d.call()` is executed more than once per page/per deferred instance?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The problem is that I'm referring to the **activeTab** which is a shared event for all the iterations.. Well, not sure if I explained that properly, may be someone could explain this better but my knowledge about the promise pattern is quite limited. Thank you!!

Comment: [That library](http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/) you used does not really implement the promise pattern :-( You might add a simple boolean variable to keep track whether the next function was already called, and otherwise not invoke `d.call()` again.

Comment: Ouch, okay. I thought that because invoking `d.call()` you're returning a deferred object and I confused that object with a promise.